# Questions on article and preposition usage

Tags: prepositions, articles

Here is my sentence:

> It is **the** special period when China faces an extremely high traffic load, which results in great transportation problems, especially **on** the railway services.

My questions:

1. Why does the author use "the" instead of "a"? My English teacher told me that there is a "a/an+adj.+n." rule.
2. Why use "on"? I usually see a problem **of**.

Comment: Please include the sentence which immediately precedes "It is the..."   as it might explain the choice of article.

Comment: You are right to question **on** here. Although the author probably has in mind the railway lines, a form of surface transport, which would license the preposition **on**, "services" is abstract, so that what he may be thinking and what he actually says are not quite the same. He could have said "problems, especially **for** the railway services".  Excess traffic creates problems **for** the railway services and **for** the department of transportation, and **for** those who use these modes of transportation, because of the congestion **on** the roadways and railways.

Comment: @TRomano Thank you very much, TRomano. The link:http://www.travelchinaguide.com/china-trains/spring-festival-rush.htm

Comment: first paragraph,line 3

Comment: @TRomano what do you think of Maulik V♦'s answer?

Comment: I think "the special period" is marginal here. It doesn't strike me as  idiomatic.  We would normally say "The time of year".

Answer (score 1):

*'...the special period'* talks about *the specific period* wherein the country faces an extremely high traffic load.

Say, on Christmas, eBay and Amazon witness a lot of traffic on their websites. So, you can call that as **the special period**.

The preposition 'on' takes care of 'high traffic load' and *not* 'problems'. Read '[restrictive/non-restrictive clauses'](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/which-versus-that-0) for further information. The string between those two commas is just added information.